# Why are my Rhythmbox controls (Pause, Play, etc.) missing from the sound menu?

Tags: 10.10, rhythmbox, indicator-sound

Rhythmbox is located in the sound menu (the tray applet where you monitor volume), however when I click it, it doesn't respond whatsoever. When I open Rhythmbox through Applications > Sound & Video, it loads just fine. The only problem here is that the control buttons are missing from the sound menu applet in the tray (pause, play, forward, rewind). Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

When in Rhythmbox select `Edit -> Preferences`, you should have in the in the `General`-tab on the bottom a drop-down menu called `Toolbar Button Labels`

Try changing the value of this drop-down, and see if the control button reappear.

This should influence both the control buttons in Rhythmbox **and** the tray applet.

Comment: No change unfortunately. I'd also like to add that when I close rhythmbox, the actual application quits and the music doesn't continue to play in the background.

Comment: Have you tried if removing and reinstalling helps? As you have multiple problems it does not seem to be a settings problem but a problem with the application it self.

Comment: Yes I have tried this, with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

After that start rhythmbox and check your preferences under Edit->Plugins, and make sure that

```
Media Server2 D-Bus Interface
MPRIS D-Bus Interface
```

are checked. Then a reboot/logout may be necessary.